# Simple List View Crashes app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-edittext

I have a simple edit text inside a dialog and I click ok after entering some text I have a list View in one fragment and I need to add that text to my listview which is in  fragment.

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
```

This is my Homefragment:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public HomeFragment(){}
    ListView lv;
    List<String> li;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.itemslistView);
        li=new ArrayList<String>();
        li.add("Apple");
        li.add("Mango");
        li.add("Orange");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String> 
        (getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list,li);
        lv.setAdapter(adp);
      return rootView;
    }
}
```

When I run this the app gets crashed and I'm not getting any error in logcat.

This is my input_dialog:

```
protected void showInputDialog() {

        // get prompts.xml view
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

        // setup a dialog window
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        // create an alert dialog
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
```

This is my Home fragment:

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    ListView lv;
    List<String> li;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
                false);
        lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.itemslistView);

        View editView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, container,
                false);
        EditText edit = (EditText) editView.findViewById(R.id.txtlist);
        String ItemName = edit.getText().toString();
        lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.itemslistView);
        li = new ArrayList<String>();
        li.add(ItemName);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list, li);
        lv.setAdapter(adp);
        return rootView;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.itemslistView);
```

to

```
lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.itemslistView);
```

in `onCreateView(...)`

Comment: @M D-I have a button if I click the button a dialog with editext appears and when I try to get that text the same thing happens the app crashes again

Comment: @M D-I have done as you said. Please see the added code

Comment: @coder Better to implement `Dialog Fragment` for this for that go to [http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-dialogfragment-example/](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-dialogfragment-example/). `Dialog Fragment` is best in this case.

Answer (score 0):

while doing this

```
lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.itemslistView);
```

you are not getting the instance of listview from this inflated view in

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
```

so while creating instance take it from rootview....i.e

```
lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.itemslistView);
```